# Cкрипт не выполняется из крона

Tags: cron, php, centos

Есть PHP-скрипт, при запуске из командной строки работает как надо.
Я прописал его в кроне:

```
0 3 * * * php /path/to/script.php param1 param2
```

По логам крона он запускается.
Но при этом в логах самого скрипта чисто и работа, которую он должен делать, не выполняется.

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема? Как можно заставить крон сохранить куда-нибудь результат (output) скрипта, может он выдает какую-то ошибку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не уверен, что Cron имеет доступ к переменным окружения, нужно попробовать изменить вызов на

```
0 3 * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/script.php param1 param2
```

Вывод в общий лог получается так

```
0 3 * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/script.php param1 param2 2>&1 | logger -t cronjob
```

Comment: Прописал путь к php - не помогло :(
А 2>&1 | logger -t cronjob не могли бы подсказать как это работает? :)

Comment: Это нужно чтобы слать стандартные выводы в файл системного лога, а -t позволяет указать имя логгера. После всего можно будет прочесть их с помощью, например, такого: grep cronjob /var/log/messages.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло :) Оказывается срипт не получал param1 и param2 (использую $argv), что решилось с помощью указания /path/to/script.php key1=param1 key2=param2 и использования $_GET

Answer (score 3):

Вообще, cron шлёт ошибки через mail пользователя, на которого повешена задача. Попробуйте посмотреть, нет ли вам локальных писем? :) И ещё стоит проверить, что переменные окружения выставлены верно и лучше прописать путь к php целиком.

Comment: Писем не приходит, но у меня сервер настроен на почту от gmail, может из-за этого письма не могут отправиться?

Comment: Так проверьте, шлются ли письма? Выполните, например, mail <yourusername>, заполните Subject, напишите какое-нибудь сообщение и нажмите Ctrl-D. Потом выполните mail и посмотите, пришло ли ваше письмо самому себе или нет.

Answer (score 2):

Я обычно использую такой подход к выполнению php-скриптов по расписанию:

```
 ∗ ∗ ∗ ∗ ∗ curl http://sitename/script.php?param1=param1value
```

Может подход и неверный, но работает.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте директорию выполнения скрипта, в кроне она обычно равна / (корневой папке), а при запуске вручную (скорее всего) - папке со скриптом. Также могут быть различия в окружении пользователей, из-под которых происходит запуск.

Comment: Я вручную запускаю из корневой папки и из под того же пользователя,  у которого прописана задача в кроне - работает как надо...